# MS Access Query/Union

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need help calculating a sum of the same field on 2 different Access tables, and displaying information from a third table. The first table SecurityInfo contains descriptions and a unique securityID field.

The Trades and Transfers table contain quantities related to the securirtyID field.

Security Info

| symbol | description | Sec ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | ABC Corp | 1 |
| DEF | DEF Corp | 2 |
| GHI | GHI Corp | 3 |

Trades

| Sec ID | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | -200 |
| 1 | -100 |
| 3 | 1000 |
| 2 | 100 |
| 1 | 300 |
| 3 | 200 |
| 2 | -300 |
| 3 | -500 |
| 1 | -300 |

Transfers

| Sec ID | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 100 |
| 3 | -200 |

I need a query which will take the securityInfo table and sum the quantity of both the trades and transfers tables by the securityID

Output

| symbol | description | Sec ID | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | ABC Corp | 1 | 200 |
| DEF | DEF Corp | 2 | -300 |
| GHI | GHI Corp | 3 | 500 |

I have been spinning my wheels, and limited to MS Access, so that knocks out quite a few of the other possibilities on the site. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use Access query designer to build two aggregate queries for Trades and Transfers. Build another query joining those two queries to Security Info. Alternative is to UNION Trades and Transfers then use that query as source for aggregate query and somewhere in there JOIN to Security Info to pull symbol and description. Advise not to use spaces in naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query :

```
select i.*, t.total + tr.total as Quantity
from Info as i
inner join (
  select Sec_ID, sum(quantity) as total
  from Trades
  group by Sec_ID
) as t on i.Sec_ID = t.Sec_ID
inner join (
  select Sec_ID, sum(quantity) as total
  from Transfers
  group by Sec_ID
) as tr on i.Sec_ID = tr.Sec_ID
```

Result :

| symbol | description | Sec_ID | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | ABC Corp | 1 | 200 |
| DEF | DEF Corp | 2 | -300 |
| GHI | GHI Corp | 3 | 500 |

Check [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/hR6yyuGB) tested it on mysql

Comment: Thanks. I am getting "syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'i.Sec_ID = t.Sec_ID inner join ( select Sec_ID, sum(quantity) total from Transfers group by Sec_ID) tr on i.Sec_ID = tr.Sec_ID, however, your table is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: However, I am getting the proper results in RazorSQL - why is this???

Comment: I have made a little update, can you check

Comment: Access is picky about parentheses in JOIN clauses. As advised in my other comment, use query designer to get correct syntax. Build the two aggregate query objects then build query joining datasets. Can copy/paste SQL of the 2 aggregate queries into final query for an all-in-one statement.